# Custom OrderedDict that returns itself

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following custom class:

```
class MyArray (OrderedDict):
    def __init__ (self,*args):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self,*args)
    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        if not hasattr (key, '__iter__'):
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,key)
        return MyArray((k,self[k]) for k in key)
```

This class does exactly what i want for when i have multiple keys, but doesn't do what i want for single keys.

Let me demonstrate what my code outputs:

```
x = MyArray()

x[0] = 3
x[1] = 4
x[2] = 5

print x[1,0,2]

MyArray([(1,4),(0,3),(2,5)])
```

But then:

```
print x[1]

4
```

I want it to be:

```
MyArray([(1,4)])
```

Here was my attempt to fix it to act the way i want (which led to infinite recursion):

```
class MyArray (OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        if not hasattr (key, '__iter__'):
            return MyArray({key:OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,key)})
        return MyArray((k,OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,k)) for k in key)
```

Comment: A quick comment on this issue: your modified class is inherently recursive. There's no way to get at the data items, no matter how deep you dive.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? what do you mean by "data items"? Are you referring to the overridden function in the answer below?

Comment: The values, `3`, `4` and `5` go in to your dictionary, but you can never get them back out. All you can get is another dictionary that contains some sub-set of them. For instance, `x[1]` is going to return `MyArray([(1, 4)])`, but so does `x[1][1]` and `x[1][1][1]`, ad infinitum.

Comment: Oh ok, yes i am aware of this, i'll continue to use OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, k) to get stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is to realize that `self[k]` is the same as `self.__getitem__(k)` so you don't want to use `self[k]` inside `__getitem__`, unless you are in fact trying to do some recursion. Instead always use `OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,key)`.

On an unrelated note, you generally don't want to create a method that just calls the same method of the parent class, ie:

```
class MyArray (OrderedDict):
    def __init__ (self,*args):
        OrderedDict.__init__(self,*args)
```

Just delete the method and python will call the parent class method for you, inheritance is awesome :).

#### update:

After some digging I found that you get infinite recursion when you try to print a `MyArray` because `OrderedDict.__repr__` calls `OrderDict.items` which then calls `OrderDict.__getitem__` (in the form of `self[key]`), then it calls `__repr__` on each of the items ... The issue here is that you're modifying `__getitem__` to do something very different than what it does in the Parent class. If you want this class to have the full functionality of a python class, you'll need to override every method that uses `self[key]` anywhere in the method. You can start with `items`, ie something like:

```
def items(self):
    'od.items() -> list of (key, value) pairs in od'
    return [(key, OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, key)) for key in self]
```

When you hit this kind of thing it's often better to drop the subclassing and just have the OrderedDict be an attribute of the new class, something like:

```
class MyArray(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.data = OrderedDict(*args)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if not hasattr (key, '__iter__'):
            return MyArray([(key, self.data[key])])
        return MyArray([(k, self.data[k]) for k in key])
```

Comment: self[k] is not the source of the recursion since it will call OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,key), the code above works, i get recursion when i try to modify it to get the behavior i want

Comment: Thanks for the tip involving the init

Comment: I didn't have **infinite** recursion for the first class (as you can see the outputs), the **infinite** recursion happens in the second class in my post above. Sorry for not specifying that the infinite one was the issue.

Comment: I know. Sorry for being cryptic. The recursion is happening in `__repr__` (as best as i can possibly know because you didn't actually include the trace in your question) not in `__getitem__`. `__repr__` gets called when you try and print a python object.

Comment: The problem was in def items, you were right. I understand what you were saying now. Thank you!! I'll update the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite recursion was happening in self.items() as **Bi Rico** pointed out. 
Here is a code that works (essentially overrides self.items())

```
class MyArray (OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__ (self, key):
        if not hasattr (key, '__iter__'):
            return MyArray({key:OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,key)})
        return MyArray((k,OrderedDict.__getitem__ (self,k)) for k in key)
    def items(self):
        '''
        called when the dictionary is printed
        '''
        return [(k, OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, k)) for k in self]
```

The code above would have worked without the items definition if I had inherited from dict instead of OrderedDict.